# Converting 3.3 volts PWM to 10V PWM

Tags: pwm, level-shifting, push-pull

I have a 3.3V PWM signal form microcontroller and i want to increase its voltage and current driving capability (at least 10mA source-sink current).

I have designed circuit like on the pic, but a am not quite satisfied how it's works.

To convert voltage level from 3.3V to 10V i have used a simple CS stage. Basing on simulation results i decided to use mos-based push-pull as a output stage (it had much better voltage levels than a bipolar push-pull).

But this design has some flaws:

1. During PWM state change i am getting a short between 10V and GND. For a short period of time both transistors are half open. It is a result of poor slew rate of a CS stage. I could improve it a bit by reducing a R3 resistance value but it would increase power consumption.
2. I am not sure if uP can drive a MOS gate. I could add resistor in series with gate, but it would increase a transition time even further and hence a power rail shorts time.

So, im looking for more handy solution or tips how could i improve my design. Maybe IC drivers exists for such a job?

[image]

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3348/187920. Then google for "half bridge driver". TI alone has over 60 parts for this, specifically designed to avoid simultaneous FET opening.

Comment: M2 turn over, drain to load, source to plus power supply. In your shematic interna diode is always conduct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, maybe it won't short.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNjNlb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The upper PMOS is capsized, so the built-in intrinsic diode is in conduction mode. You should swap Drain and Source to have a correct orientation.

Comment: you might explain why connecting the PMOS right way round makes such a difference...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Okey-dokey, I have edited the answer with little more detail.